# Complete days in data from a DataFrame grouped by group by

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have this Dataframe:
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peX67.jpg)
I applied df.groupby ('site') to classify data by this feature.

```
   grouped = Datos.groupby('site')
```

After classifying it I want to complete, for all records, the "date" column day by day.
The procedure that I think I should follow will be:
1. Generate a complete sequence between start and end date. (Step completed).

```
for site in grouped:
    dates = ['2018-01-01', '2020-01-17']
    startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime( dates[0], "%Y-%m-%d") # parse first date
    endDate   = datetime.datetime.strptime( dates[-1],"%Y-%m-%d") # parse last date 
    days = (endDate - startDate).days  # how many days between?
    allDates = {datetime.datetime.strftime(startDate+datetime.timedelta(days=k), 
                                        "%Y-%m-%d"):0 for k in range(days+1)}
```

2. Compare this sequence with the column 'date' of my groupby. ('Site) and add those that are not present do not match the dates in' date '.
3. Write a function or loop that allows you to update the 'date' column with the new dates and also complete the missing values with 0.

```
(grouped.apply(add_days))
```

So far I have only managed to complete step 1, so I ask for your help to complete steps 2 and 3.
I would very much appreciate your always important help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had to do quiet the same thing for a project:
Maybe it's not the best solution for you but it can help you. (and I hope save you the headache I had)
Here is how as I managed it with help of https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

```
df_DateRange=pd.DataFrame()
df_1=pd.DataFrame()
grouped=pd.DataFrame()

#1. Create a DataFrame with alldays (your step2):
#Create a DataFrame with alldays
dates_list = ['2019-12-31', '2020-01-05']
df_DateRange['date']=pd.date_range(start=dates_list [0],end=dates_list [-1],freq='1D')
df_DateRange['date']=df_DateRange['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df_DateRange.set_index(['date'],inplace=True)

#Set index of you Datos DataFrame:
Datos.set_index(['date'], inplace=True)

#Join both DataFrame:
df_1=df_DateRange.join(Datos)


#2. Replace the NaN:
df_1['site'].fillna("", inplace=True)
df_1['value'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_1['value2'].fillna(0, inplace=True)


#3. do the calculation:
grouped = df_1.groupby('site').sum()
```

df_DateRange:
      date
0  2019-12-31
1  2020-01-01
2  2020-01-02
3  2020-01-03
4  2020-01-04
5  2020-01-05

Datos:
         date   site  value  value2
0  2020-01-01  site1      1      -1
1  2020-01-01  site2      2      -2
2  2020-01-02  site1     10     -10
3  2020-01-02  site2     20     -20

df1:
             site  value  value2
date
2019-12-31           0.0     0.0
2020-01-01  site1    1.0    -1.0
2020-01-01  site2    2.0    -2.0
2020-01-02  site1   10.0   -10.0
2020-01-02  site2   20.0   -20.0
2020-01-03           0.0     0.0
2020-01-04           0.0     0.0
2020-01-05           0.0     0.0

grouped=
       value  value2
site
         0.0     0.0
site1   11.0   -11.0
site2   22.0   -22.0